# dpkg command spontaneously killed on first run, works second time

Tags: debian, dpkg, packaging

I have a home made Debian package that installs two scripts files, two systemd services and a tar file. The handmade maintainer scripts are preinst, post inst, prerm and postrm.

The problem I'm currently having is when I run `dpkg --purge <PACKAGE>` the process gets killed by something (I'm unsure what):

```
root@host:/data# dpkg --purge <PACKAGE> 
(Reading database ... 32393 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing <PACKAGE> (<VERSION) ...
Terminated
root@host:/data# echo $?
143
root@host:/data#
```

The second time I run the exact same command, it works fine.

```
root@host:/data# dpkg --purge <PACKAGE> 
(Reading database ... 32393 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing <PACKAGE> (<VERSION>) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing <PACKAGE>, unable to remove directory '/data': Device or resource busy - directory may be a mount point?
Purging configuration files for <PACKAGE> (<VERSION>) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing web-chroot, unable to remove directory '/data': Device or resource busy - directory may be a mount point?
root@host:/data#
```

***Note:*** `/data` is in fact a mount point, and it is not owned by any other Debian packages, so `dpkg` tries (and fails) to remove it. This is supposedly expected behavior of Debian's implementation of `dpkg`.

My question is, **why is the dpkg --purge process getting killed the first time it is run?** What would be killing it?

**I've tried checking all kinds of logs, including:**

- `/var/log/dpkg.log`
- `/var/log/apt/history.log`
- `/var/log/apt/term.log`
- `/var/lib/dpkg/info/<PACKAGE>.*` (`.list`, `.prerm`, `.postrm`, `.preinst`, `.postinst`)

But nothing is giving me any helpful indicator of what is going on.

---

***Note:*** The Debian package gets installed onto a Debian 8 32-bit system

## **The Details:**

The Debian package installs the files in the following locations:

- `/~/start-fs.sh`
- `/~/stop-fs.sh`
- `/data/file-system_<VERSION>.tar.gz`
- `/etc/systemd/system/file-system.service`
- `/etc/systemd/system/file-system-helper.service`

The maintainer scripts are as follows:

`preinst`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Stop services if they are running and disable them
systemctl is-active --quiet file-system && systemctl stop file-system > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
sleep 1
systemctl disable --quiet file-system.service || true
systemctl is-active --quiet file-system-helper && systemctl stop file-system-helper > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
# Remove any previous tars that could share the same name as the tar artifact
rm -f /data/file-system*.tar.gz
exit 0
```

`postinst`

```
#!/bin/bash

error() {
    echo "$1"
    exit 1
}

# Untar the artifact in the /data directory
tar -xzf /data/file-system*.tar.gz --directory /data || error "Could not untar artifact"
# Remove tar artifact, as it has already been untarred
rm -f /data/file-system*.tar.gz
# Restart systemctl daemon to let it know about new service files
systemctl daemon-reload
# Enable service if it is not running and enable it
systemctl is-active --quiet file-system || systemctl start file-system
systemctl enable --quiet file-system.service
exit 0
```

`prerm`

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Stop services if they are running and disable them
systemctl is-active --quiet file-system && systemctl stop file-system.service > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
sleep 3
systemctl disable --quiet file-system.service || true
systemctl is-active --quiet file-system-helper && systemctl stop file-system-helper.service > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
exit 0
```

`postrm`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Remove scripts
rm -f /root/start-fs.sh
rm -f /root/stop-fs.sh
# Remove fs in data dir
rm -rf /data/file-system/
# Remove any possible leftover artifacts (shouldn't be any)
rm -f /data/file-system*.tar.gz
# Remove systemd services
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/file-system-helper.service
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/file-system.service
exit 0
```

When I run `dpkg -s <PACKAGE>` the first time it becomes **`half-configured`** which according to `dpkg` means `The package is unpacked and configuration has been started, but not yet completed for some reason.`

```
root@host:/data# dpkg -s <PACKAGE>
[...]
Status: purge ok half-configured
[...]
```

Also if I manually run the `./prerm` script and then manually run the `./postrm` script after installing with `dpkg -i <PACKAGE>` the package is successfully uninstalled and files are correctly removed.

Comment: 143 suggests `SIGTERM`. Since this is happening on purge, could you post the contents of your `prerm` and `postrm`?

Comment: @StephenKitt All maintainer scripts have been posted.

Comment: Are there any "kill" commands in /root/stop-fs.sh? If you run the `dpkg --purge` the **first** time is this file removed?

Comment: @icarus there are some `pkill` commands that kill processes, but this should only be run when `systemctl stop file-system` is called -- `/root/stop-fs.sh` is the `ExecStop=` of `file-system.service`

Comment: @Wimateeka That systemctl is executed during your prerm.

Comment: @icarus Yup! I'm, aware :). I mis-understood your question, I thought you were asking if the purge command was calling the script `/root/stop-fs.sh` directly. I'm currently checking if the purge command removes the script the first time.

Comment: @jordanm thanks for pointing that out so I didn't need to. Whilst not guaranteed, the name of the script made it a good bet for being the ExecStop, which is why I asked about it. It would be interesting to see the exact `pkill` lines, in case they are killing rather more than is expected.

Comment: @icarus it is not removing the script files that are in `/~/` the first time. It does remove the second time. Also for debugging this I actually placed `echo` commands at the start of and after every command in both my pre/post  inst/rm files. For the `purge`, it gets through all of the `prerm` the first time, but none of the `postrm`. The second time it goes through all of the `prerm` and then all of the `postrm` and then all of the `postrm` again.

Comment: After running `purge` the first time, `dpkg -s <PACKAGE>` shows `Status: purge ok half-configured`, and the second time shows `dpkg-query: package '<PACKAGE>' is not installed and no information is available`. According to `dpkg: half-configured - The package is unpacked and configuration has been started, but not yet completed for some reason.` I can't even find how to get to the `half-configured` state on [the Debian Maintainer Script reference site](https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts). Why would it fail like this?

Comment: Adding `set -x` as the first line of the scripts is simpler than adding echo commands.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to reimplement what dpkg is supposed to be doing from within the maintainer scripts, but without taking into account all the ways these can be called.

For example prerm and postrm will also be called during upgrades!

My recommendation would be to simply avoid doing the strange dance with the tar, and provide these files directly within the .deb, and to stop manually removing any files shipped in the .deb. Just let dpkg handle the unpacking and removals when it is needed.

Then for when to call the systemd stuff you should check the maintainer script flow charts, either from Debian policy or from the various deb- man pages (although these are currently less detailed).